# SimpleXLSX, как получить полу-жирное поле

Tags: php, html5, simplexlsx

Работаю с `SimpleXLSX` библиотекой [github](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx)
Имею вот такую гугл таблицу https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jgTudPoIzHIoJU6BZ5Hm5pJAwVoEjV4_dFjSbsPg7UQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать из этой таблицы ассоциативный масив/объект(чтобы вернуть на front), типа:

```php
[
['Безопасность'] => [
   ['Записи'] => [
     '1 статья бла бла', '2 статья бла бла'
   ]
],
['Наполнение канала'] => [
   ['Записи'] => [
     '1 статья бла бла', '2 статья бла бла', '3 статья бла бла', '4 статья бла бла', '5 статья бла бла'
   ]
]
]
```

НО, не понимаю как работать с библиотекой. У меня получилось сделать только так:

```php
require_once('simplexlsx-master/src/SimpleXLSX.php');

$filename = 'file.xlsx'; // путь к файлу

function echo_print_r($arr) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
}

if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse($filename)) {
    $header_values = $rows = [];
    foreach ( $xlsx->rows() as $k => $r ) {
        if ( $k === 0 ) {
            $header_values = $r;
            continue;
        }
        $rows[] = array_combine( $header_values, $r );
    }
    echo_print_r( $rows );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, всё проблема заключается в том, что нужно понять где полу-жирные поля, но я не знаю как эта функция называется и есть ли она вообще